# Angular typeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects

Tags: angular, routes

in Angular 8 ,when i do below to add routing for a component, inside this,router.config got below error.

```
let test = { path: 'sample', loadChildren: () => 
import("./screens/sample/sample.component").then(m => m.sampleComponent) } as Route;
this.router.config.push(test);
```

typeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them

Comment: loadChildren component doesn't exist . only modules

Answer (score 1):

I am no longer on angular 8, but if memory serves me well, you cannot lazy-load a component, only modules.